# failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, arm

I am trying to cross compile a c code with arm microprocessor using `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc` in Ubuntu 18.04.My code uses a static library `libc_nonshared.a`. When I am compiling, it shows the following error:

```
/opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.9.11-1.0.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/real-ld: error: network uses VFP register arguments, /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS) does not
/opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.9.11-1.0.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/real-ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS)
```

After 2 days of searching, I got to know that the issue is happening due to soft linking and it can be solved by adding a flag `'-mfloat-abi=hard'` in Makefile.

I added a line in my Makefile (`CFLAGS=-mfloat-abi=hard`). But it's not making any difference in error. Can anyone tell me where should I add this? or else what changes I need to make in my Makefile.

Comment: Do you have a file name 'network.c'?  The binary `libc_nonshared.a` is probably compiled for a system without an FPU.  The `libc` is compile probably compiled with `-mfloat=soft`.  If you know you have a FPU, you can use `-mfloat=softfp` to link these.  https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/10/11/demystifying-arm-floating-point-compiler-options/  and https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort

Comment: Thank you for your reply.yes I have a file network.c.